# spring jaxb exception

Tags: spring, jaxb, jaxb2

```
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller">
    <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="myclass"/>
</oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>
```

I keep getting exception:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.http.MediaType.sortBySpecificity(Ljava/util/List;)V

What is the problem here?
whole stack trace:

```
2010-09-10 21:02:53 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
```

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.http.MediaType.sortBySpecificity(Ljava/util/List;)V
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.getMediaTypes(ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.java:295)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.resolveViewName(ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.java:355)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.resolveViewName(DispatcherServlet.java:1091)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:195)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:159)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:141)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:90)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:417)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at com.springsource.insight.collection.tcserver.request.HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.invoke(HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.java:60)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:379)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a sign of library version mismatch. You should either upgrade spring, or upgrade the other library that is replying on it. (Or possibly downgrade any of them)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to include a `BeanNameViewResolver` in your the `viewResolvers` list?  Alternatively, put it in the `defaultViews` list.  I can't tell exactly how you want the view resolution to occur.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="xml" value="#{subscribersXml.contentType}" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="order" value="0"/>
    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Reference: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multiple-representations